# my screen just went black

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My Samsung galaxy s3 just went black and now it won't turn on and when I try to turn it on it just vibrates. I tried restarting it I tried taking my battery out. That don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Just let it recharge for some time then try again